# Why is my League of Legends client crashing and experiencing multiple bugs?

Tags: league-of-legends, pc, windows-8

Somehow, after upgrading my laptop to Windows 8, my League of Legends client tends to crash while the game is loading (after champion selection).

I have to manually kill the client in Task Manager, re-log into the client, and launch the match again. This occurs on an average of 5-20 times in a single session before I could get into the match.

When I do get into a match, the in-game screen is bugged: I can't see my champion, stats, other players/enemies..nothing.

I also find that after a crash, the game takes a long time to spawn the champion in the match. The progress goes from 0% - 35% then stops, and then it starts moving about 1% every 2-3 minutes.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: This problem is in the client, not your windows version. I have personally known many players to experience it on many different computer systems and OSs. For example, your having the issue on windows 8, but I always had the issue on windows 7, and stopped having it mostly when I upgraded to windows 8. Some players have reported that reinstalling the game has shown some positive results.

Comment: Most problems like this are caused by driver problems

Answer (score 5):

The League of Legends Client runs on Adobe Air, so the issue could be with that software.  I would check for updates to Adobe Air.  You can also try running the client in [Windows 7 compatibility mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/older-programs-compatible-version-windows).

Comment: I tried doing that. In some cases it would load fine and then the problem would re-occur again when I play more matches in Windows 7 compatibility mode.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to blame the client as it does crash occasionally, but if it is repeatedly it has to be something on your computer. Typically you are missing some software updates. Try making sure windows 8 has all the updates as well as your video card. Even if you complain to Riot about it they will tell you, you need to upgrade your software. They are usually right.

Comment: True, I will seek out any pending updates with Windows. Probably updating to Windows 8.1 might help too along with any other security updates and such.

Comment: This is just good advice in general.  ANY time you have issues with software not running appropriately make sure all of your drivers are up to date before seeking other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

League of legends has a new client that might fix your issues. The bugs are probably a result of adobe air like stated but [this new client](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/featured/preseason-2017/client) doesn't use adobe air!

I know this doesn't directly answer why you have bugs but hopefully it fixes the bugs all together :D

Comment: This client is in beta and will probably have bugs of its own, just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having issues with League freezing my computer, and it only happened while playing League, **but** I found [a solution](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3385940) where it said to cap the frame rate at 30 FPS.

> SOLUTION:
>   I have manually capped the framerate at 30 fps and have not had a crash since.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. In my case I had to use procexplorer because task manager would only close the game client exe and leave the lolclient.exe in the processes. So when I would click reconnect I would get a crashed message or it would freeze up.
The steps I took to fixing it was;

- Get rid of Windows 8.

When this problem started on windows 10 I wanted to go back to 7 again.

{Please keep in mind that the following steps were performed on windows 8 aswell and while they did fix the issue, I did not like the OS due to other games and programs performing poorly even after the OS updates they constantly suggested}

- Instead I updated my OS and Video Drivers. I then Re-Installed League
  of legends.

This might not be the best solution but if it does fail also;

- Check your anti-virus and add the league of legends folder to your
  exception list.
- Check your alternate dns and use 8.8.8.8 .
- Finally go to

  C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\projects\lol_game_client\releases\ {Latest version}

Now just remove/delete (back the files up first) the two files there "releasemanifest" and "S_OK". From previous experience I can tell you that all this does is recheck you game client and if there are files to be updated it updates them. The problem with doing this is that you may have to manually update your game client again in future. This is why its better to just reinstall LOL however this is good as a quick fix if the problem is client related.